# Prove that this number is irrational it's involve the exponential

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Prove that $2^{\sqrt{3}}$ is irrational or even it is transcendental? I am wondering if there exists the method that describes its property and its irrationality of these kinds (or even with some numbers of the form like $5^{\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt[4]{2}}}$), which involves only with the algebraic number

Comment: [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Neretin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem): if $a,b$ are algebraic, $a \ne 0,1$, $b$ irrational, then all values of $a^b$ are transcendental.

So: $2^{\sqrt{3}}$ is transcendental.

To show
$$
5^{\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[4]{2}}\right)}
\tag1$$
is transcendental, it suffices to show
$$
\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[4]{2}}
\tag2$$
is irrational.  I leave that to you, using the rational root theorem.

Note: Numerically evaluating $(2)$ we get $1.8709999$ so we may mistakenly think it is rational.  In fact with more digits it is $1.8709999455101501528$.

Comment: Thank you and if i'm not wrong let $x=\sqrt{2}+\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt[4]{2}}$ is a root of $(x^2+2x-3)^2=18 \Longrightarrow x^4+4x^3-2x^2-12x-9=0$ and the rational root theorem says that, if $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$, $x$ is an integer since $q|1$ and $4^2<(x^2+2x-3)^2=18<5^2$ which is not possible.

Comment: I would say: from $x^4+4x^3-2x^2-12x-9=0$, look at the $9$ constant term (and the $1$ coefficient of $x^4$).  If it has a rational root, it must be one of $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 9$.  Trying all these, I see that none of them is a solution.  So it has no rational roots.

Comment: Interesting aside.  $(2)$ is equal to $\displaystyle -1+\sqrt{4+3\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Definitely, professor.